# Work with javascript from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        window.location.href = '/dash/do/record/' + $('#filename').val()
        return false;
    });
});
```

written as `<script src="...jquery..."></script>` and `<script>... the code </script>`

If I load it right from the browser, it works, but if it is called through an iframe, not. What's the reason? What should I do? (The main page has the jquery tag, too)

Comment: So are you trying to redirect the iframe or the parent window ?

Comment: An iframe is a separate document. You'd need to reference `parent.document`.

Comment: `$('#filename').$` what is this representing?

Comment: @isherwood I need just the iframe redirect

Comment: @Jai that stands for a input that has a value which determines the name of the file that's gonna be recorded, as you see in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if you are executing this script from an `iframe` which is a child window then you have to use `parent`:

```
window.parent.location.href = "";
```

*want to redirect the iframe, not the whole page.*

Then you can create a function on parent page to change the `src` of the `iframe`:

#### on parent page:

```
function changeSrc(url){
   $('iframe').attr('src', url);
}
```

#### on iframe document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
      window.parent.changeSrc('/dash/do/record/' + $('#filename').val());
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: @want to redirect the iframe, not the whole page. I have a important thing to display that's why I separate the content and the other thing into iframes

Comment: okay! then you can create a function to change src of the iframe on the parent page and call it from iframe's page.

Comment: just that easy? ok thanks I'll do so. But sure that with changing the src it reloads the page?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde see my answer. Jai's should work as well!

Comment: Yes, that is. But about the thing of .$, what was a trouble with pico, that shows that when the line is not complete, it is .val(). Does .$ do something, @Jai ? and do I need to still return false?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde may be that will append the jquery function in the url as `$` is the alias for `jQuery`

Comment: Well you can takeout the `return false;` but i recommend you to use it if this is in any form element, otherwise you can surely take it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to redirect the iframe to a new site. Most likely your browser is protecting you from Cross Site Scripting. I tried to replicate your results by redirecting my iFrame to Google. My console subsequently popped an error and now reads the following:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EAiWU_TDMKuC8QfC4YG4DA&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

You can still redirect the parent by using :

```
window.top.location.href = '/dash/do/record/' + $('#filename').$
```

Or redirect the iframe itself with:

```
window.top.$('iframe')[0].src = ""
```

Comment: thanks, but I just want to redirect the frame, not the whole page. That's the important point.